# CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension

Tags: jquery, html

I get this error when i try to .load() another html file into the div of the calling html file.

```
    <title>SubSuggester.com</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/reddit_icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.secondDivID').load("login.html");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Could some one please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)